# Probability inequality in Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, expected-value, markov-chains

**Problem:** Let $(Z_n)_{n\ge0}$ be a Markov chain such that $Z_0=1$, $Z_n \ge 0$ almost surely and $\mathbb{P}(Z_n>0)>0$. Prove that
$$\mathbb{P}(Z_n>0) \ge \dfrac{\mathbb{E}(Z_n)^2}{\mathbb{E}(Z_n^2)}.$$
**My attempt:** I have already tried to prove it by showing that $\mathbb{P}(Z_n>0)\times \mathbb{E}(Z_n^2) \ge \mathbb{E}(Z_n)^2$ with some basic technique like Bunyakovski inequality,...But I have not still done with this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(EZ_n)^{2}=(EZ_n1_{Z_n >0})^{2}\leq EZ_n^{2}E1_{Z_n >0}^{2}=P(Z_n >0) EZ_n^{2}$. (I have used Cauchy-Schwarz-Bunyakovski inequality).

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your approach to this problem was very simple and easy to understand.